# depends_on "A static list expression is required."

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

I'm using the depends_on block with a condition check while creating object storage. Surprisingly, I saw the following error. Any pointers on how to resolve it?

code:

```
locals {
        is_gov = local.realm == "oc2" || local.realm == "oc3" ? true : false
    }
    

resource "oci_identity_compartment" "gov_comp" {
  compartment_id = var.comp1
  description    = "GOV COMP"
  name           = "gov_comp"

  defined_tags  = { "Operations.CostCenter" = "001" }
  freeform_tags = { "Department" = "Executives" }
}

resource "oci_identity_compartment" "non_gov_comp" {
  compartment_id = var.comp3
  description    = "commerical comp"
  name           = "non_gov_cmop"

  defined_tags  = { "Operations.CostCenter" = "000" }
  freeform_tags = { "Department" = "Non-Executives" }
}

resource "oci_objectstorage_bucket" "test_bucket" {
  compartment_id = var.compartment_id
  name           = var.bucket_name
  namespace      = var.bucket_namespace

  depends_on = is_gov ? [oci_identity_compartment.gov_comp] : [oci_identity_compartment.non_gov_comp]
}


Error:

depends_on = local.is_gov ? [oci_identity_compartment.gov_comp] : [   
   
A static list expression is required.
```

Comment: The error message explains that you cannot specify a dynamically resolved value for the `depends_on` meta-argument. Does something prevent you from specifying both resources in the list?

Comment: thanks for looking at it. Could you pls elaborate on "both resources in the list"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `gov_comp` and `non_gov_comp` are always created toghether. They are not exclusive. Thus your `test_bucket` should be create when both these resources get created:

```
resource "oci_objectstorage_bucket" "test_bucket" {
  compartment_id = var.compartment_id
  name           = var.bucket_name
  namespace      = var.bucket_namespace

  depends_on = [oci_identity_compartment.gov_com, oci_identity_compartment.non_gov_comp]
}
```